# What difference does it make to a Library if it supports abstraction and structured programming?

Tags: language-agnostic, abstraction

I was told that the functions are different in a Library because they generally support abstraction and structured programming, I'm wondering what that means?

What functions do Libraries have because of abstraction and structured programming?

Is that too vague of a question?

Comment: Yeah, a little too vague. Can you narrow it down to a particular language?

Answer (score 0):

Smells like marketing speak to me.

Any library should provide some abstraction. Otherwise you could as well code the stuff provided by the library yourself.

And about structured programming, this is something the user of the library is responsible for. I cannot think of any library that prevents the user from structured programming.